# Prevent transcoding when airdropping HEVC video

Tags: macos, high-sierra, video, file-sharing, airdrop

When I use AirDrop to send photos from iPhone 8, iPhone X and iPhone 12 (regardless of iOS system) to my 2017 macbook pro (High Sierra), `sharingd` automatically converts the HEVC video into AVC format. I don't need this as HEVC is basically supported on all of my (and other people I know) devices, especially considering that this transcoding process takes longer than the actual transmission.

I have already selected the "Keep Originals" for the "Transfer to Mac or PC" option in iPhone setting.

Is it possible for me to disable this behavior?

Edit: This no longer happens on my new m1 MBP, nor does it happen in macOS Monterey on my old 2017 MBP. I guess High Sierra is still considered an old system and therefore HEVC is not fully supported.

Comment: If you save the video to Files, use Files to compress it, then airdrop the zip, does it get transcoded?

Comment: Probably won't.

Comment: @Ezekiel Yes, verified it won't. But this is still a bit inconvenient, similar to how I would previously kill `sharingd` when it starts transcoding and go to the temp folder to fetch the video files.

Answer (score 2):

Open the Settings app, go to Photos and select "Keep Originals" for the "Transfer to Mac or PC" option.

Tested with iOS 15.